# symfony doctrine orm mappings wildcard

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

Symfony 6.3

I want to place entities in multiple subfolders, for now i have a config like this:

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App\Core:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Core/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Core\Entity'
            alias: AppCore
        App\Shared:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Shared/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Shared\Entity'
            alias: AppShared
        App\Chat:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Chat/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Chat\Entity'
            alias: AppChat
        App\User:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/User/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\User\Entity'
            alias: AppUser
```

Now, if i adding a new "module" with entities in subfolder, i should add a new config.

Is there any way to apply wildcard to this config? Something like this:

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/*/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

I try to do so, but it not working.

Comment: Why not just remove the mappings while `auto_mapping` is enabled? It doesn't matter where your Entities are located, as long as they are annotated correctly.

Comment: if i do so, i getting the error: 'Could not find the entity manager for class "App\\Core\\Entity\\Role". Check your Doctrine configuration to make sure it is configured to load this entity’s metadata.' In the Role class i have Entity attribute: `#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: RoleRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "core_role")]
class Role {}`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try the following config. I'm not sure if it works, I haven't tested it.

```yaml
mappings:
    App:
        is_bundle: false
        type: attribute
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/'
        prefix: 'App'
        alias: App
```

I'm not sure what else would happen to your other classes and the Symfony DI Container internally.

Also don't forget to disable the autoloader for all those locations using the exclude list in your `services.yaml` file:

```yaml
App\:
   exclude:
     - '../src/*/Entity'   // not sure if you can use `**` as glob pattern here
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are splitting your code by domain.

```
Core\
Core\Entity\
Shared\
Shared\Entity\
Chat\
Chat\Entity\
User\
User\Entity\
```

This architecture looks like the older Symfony bundle system, and if you want to ease your symfony configuration, you'd better declare these directories as bundles.

It's only 1 file to add and a bit of configuration:

<kbd>Core\CoreBundle.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class CoreBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

And its declaration in <kbd>config/bundles.php</kbd>

```
<?php

return [
    // ...
    App\Core\CoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

From here, configure the mapping as a bundle and Doctrine will automatically seek for entities in the `Core\Entity` directory.

```
mappings:
    App\Core:
        is_bundle: true
        type: attribute
        alias: AppCore
```

You can read more about bundles [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html)

Be advised that Symfony [doesn't recommend to create bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#don-t-create-any-bundle-to-organize-your-application-logic) except for reusable components.

> Don't Create any Bundle to Organize your Application Logic
>
> When
> Symfony 2.0 was released, applications used bundles to divide their
> code into logical features: UserBundle, ProductBundle, InvoiceBundle,
> etc. However, a bundle is meant to be something that can be reused as
> a stand-alone piece of software.
>
> If you need to reuse some feature in your projects, create a bundle
> for it (in a private repository, do not make it publicly available).
> For the rest of your application code, use PHP namespaces to organize
> code instead of bundles.

Comment: i just want to organize the code, i dont need a bundles

Answer (score -1):

i do something similar - but i use the xml mapping.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: false
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: xml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/schema/'
                prefix: 'App\Domain'
```

schema/Order.OrderItem.orm.xml:

`<entity name="App\Domain\Order\OrderItem">`

schema/Product.Inventory.orm.xml:
`<entity name="App\Domain\Product\Inventory">`

So the entity name tells doctrine where to look for the entity class. I dont know if it would work with annotation/attributes the same way.
(but as the XML is a bit broken with doctrine-extensions and orm - i will have to face this problem in the near future..)